# Jquery UI Accordion Header Formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the JQuery UI accordion in my JQuery UI modal dialog. My code is identical to several working examples I've found on the web (especially http://jsfiddle.net/eKb8J/). The suspect the culprit is CSS related, but do not know how the fix the issue.

I'm using JQuery UI 1.8.7 and JQuery 1.7.2.

**The Problem**
Essentially, the arrow and header vertical bar are not aligned with the accordion header, making it look really sloppy. I'd like the header to appear on the same line as the arrow and the header vertical bar.
Screenshot of issue posted:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpn1H.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

When I look at the elements in FireFox using Ctrl-Shift-I, I get:
The CSS applied to the accordion element: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCpSe.png
The CSS applied to the header element within the accordion: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD2tM.png

Comment: if possible link your css file to the jsFiddle, then we would be able to replicated the issue. But you are right, somewhere styles are overwriting the default ones.

Comment: It can't really be replicated in jsFiddle, as it's integrated into an ASP.net environment.

Comment: It's hard to fix this problem without the original source. What you can do to solve the problem is use the Inspector (or better yet, the Firefox plugin "Firebug") to see what styles are being used by your elements and disable/enable and change them realtime. Using those tools and a bit of CSS knowledge, you should be able to fix this problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A URL where we can view the code would be helpful. Also, trying downloading the latest version of Firefox, visiting your page, and clicking Ctrl+Shift+I. Then click on the element in question. This is a very quick way to narrow down the CSS culprit.

Comment: I inspected the elements in the new FireFox and posted the screenshots to the CSS in my post above.